# Is there a word for fan reaction at the sight of their idol?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, nouns, adjectives

Like the screaming, screeching, swooning, fainting and crying reaction of fans at seeing a pop star?

Comment: For a single word request, "YOU MUST INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used." (See the tag.)

Answer (score 2):

See **berserk** at [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/berserk), often used in the phrase **go berserk**, defined as

> Out of control with anger or excitement; wild or frenzied.

**going wild** and **went crazy** are other popular options.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest *hysteria*. From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hysteria):

> behavior exhibiting overwhelming or unmanageable fear or emotional excess

Especially in the usage *fan hysteria*. An example is this sentence from [The Ashgate Research Companion to Fan Cultures](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=ZCAHDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA165#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> In stark contrast to ... Vermorel's lovesick pop fans, Jenkins argued that representations of **fan hysteria** were examples of media stereotyping

Answer (score 1):

There's [star-struck](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/starstruck?s=t), which refers to someone enchanted by entertainment stars, but that doesn't quite cover the extremity of the reaction you mention. [Fangirling](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fangirl?s=t) seems more apt: "to demonstrate intense excitement at the mention or in the presence of a particular celebrity, film, product, etc., especially one associated with popular culture or technology."

For an explanation of the phenomenon see, [Beatlemaniacs, Beliebers, Directioners — why do they scream?](https://www.washingtonpost.com/lifestyle/style/beatlemaniacs-beliebers-directioners--why-do-they-scream/2014/07/24/ae5437b4-1273-11e4-9285-4243a40ddc97_story.html) which offers this explanation from Rachel Simmons, author of [The Curse of the Good Girl](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/014311798X)

> “When men cry at a sports event, it’s very similar” to the screaming
>   that takes place at a One Direction concert, says author Rachel
>   Simmons. “It wouldn’t be okay for men to do that anywhere else. But
>   the sporting event sanctions that behavior.”
>
> Simmons is the author of “The Curse of the Good Girl,” a book in which
>   she argues that young women are unfairly asked to squeeze into an
>   impossible mold of politeness and modesty. Simmons says a concert is a
>   unique event that gives girls the rare opportunity to break out of
>   those roles.
>
> “In their day-to-day, non-concert-going lives, girls don’t have a lot
>   of permission to scream,” she says. “A concert offers an oasis from
>   the daily rules about being good girls. Screaming is about letting go
>   and leaving the confines of being the self-conscious pleaser.”